# Ansible include_task based on condition (directory empty or certifcate is expired or 30 days remaining in expiry)

Tags: ansible, letsencrypt

I am using Ansible [`letsencrypt`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/letsencrypt_module.html) module to generate SSL certificates. The playbook is working fine, the certificate is generated and applied.

Now I want that this task is only played when certain conditions are matched, otherwise skipped this task.

Condition:

- If `/etc/letsencrypt/certs` directory is emtpy (when running first time)

OR

- If 30 days are remaining in certificate  expiry date

OR

- If certificate is expired

Could anyone please confirm the commands to achieve this.

Example:

```yaml
- include_tasks: tasks/letsencrypt-issue-jetty.yml
  when: >
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look into Ansible [Conditionals](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html).

```yaml
- include_tasks: tasks/letsencrypt-issue-jetty.yml
  when: certs_in_dir == 0 or days_remaining <= 30 or certificate_expired
```

So in general your provided approach will work already.

For creating and and loading the variables with values, you may have a look into

- [`set_fact` – Set host variable(s) and fact(s)](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_fact_module.html)
- [Using Variables - Registering variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables)

as well into

- [What's the difference between `include_tasks` and `import_tasks`?](https://serverfault.com/a/875292/448950)

Answer (score 0):

I used the below steps to the achieve the target. It is working but let me know if anything can be corrected.

```
    - name: 'Check /etc/letsencrypt/certs is empty or not'
      command: ls /etc/letsencrypt/certs
      ignore_errors: True
      register: FoundFiles   
   
    - name: "Get a cert from an https port"
      get_certificate:
        host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        port: 443
      delegate_to: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
      run_once: true
      ignore_errors: True
      register: cert
    
    - name: "Cert expiry status"
      vars:
       expire_status: "{{ (( cert.expired )) }}"
      shell: echo "{{ expire_status }}"
      ignore_errors: True
      register: Expiry_Result
    
    - name: "How many days until cert expires"
      vars:
        expire_days: "{{ (( cert.not_after | to_datetime('%Y%m%d%H%M%SZ')) - (ansible_date_time.iso8601 | to_datetime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')) ).days }}"
      shell: echo "{{ expire_days }}"
      ignore_errors: True
      register: Num_of_ExpiryDays

   - include_tasks: tasks/letsencrypt-issue-jetty.yml
when: FoundFiles.stdout == "" or Expiry_Result.stdout == 'True' or Num_of_ExpiryDays.stdout | int <= 14
```